# Flex: datagrid select all items

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

What would be the best way to select all items in a datagrid.

I was thinking of doing a for loop and then select each item, but is there a better way for achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What type of dataProvider are you using?

If you have an array, you can do this:

```
dataGrid.selectedItems = dataGrid.dataProvider;
```

If you have an ArrayCollection you can do this:

```
dataGrid.selectedItems = dataGrid.dataProvider.source;
```

For XML, you'll probably have to loop.

More info on the selectedItems property:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItems

Comment: @Adnan @Reboog711 If you have to care about data type, you're probably on the wrong way. `selectedItems` represents a subset of data `dataProvider`. Setting it sounds error-prone. Changing `selectedIndices` is much more secure and elegant.

Comment: @Destroyica I don't think I understand your comment.  In a Flex MX List; the dataProvider is a generic object; so any manipulation of it will need to be aware of the type.  The selectedItems property must contains elements of the dataProvider.  Changing selectedIndices requires a loop--as mentioned in the original question--but I think it would make the code less elegant.  I do not understand how using selectedIndices would make the code more (or less) secure than accessing selectedItems.

Comment: my point is that manipulating indices lets the component deals with data. By setting the `selectedItems` you send data to the component that may be (totally) different from the `dataProvider`. I'm pretty sure that when you set `selectedItems` the components has to check consistency between those two collections - But it works as ActionScript is very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I also tried all these with mx.dataGrid but doesn't work,
Here I fond a good way

```
var indexArr:Array = [];
for(var i:uint= 0; i<dataGrid.dataProvider.length;i++ )
{

    indexArr.push(i);    

} 
dataGrid.selectedIndices= indexArr;
```

this works for me

Answer (score 2):

I'll also add the complementary of this question. 
To unselect all items of a datagrid, the answer is not

```
dataGrid.selectedItems = null;
```

But we'll be

```
dataGrid.selectedItems = new Array;
```

The first will throw NullPointerExceptions.